# Array Assertion Failed

Tags: javascript

I am trying to understand why my test failed...

```
function test(expected, testName) {
  if (!expected) {
    console.log(testName);
  } else {
    console.log('test passed');
  }
}

function testMyArray(arr1, arr2) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    if (arr1[i] !== arr2[i]) {
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }
}


var arr1 = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10];
var arr2 = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10];
var arr3 = [2, 10, 6, 8, 12];
var arr4 = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12];

test(testMyArray(arr1, arr4) === false, 'false if input not eq') // should say false
test(testMyArray(arr1, arr2) === true, 'true if input eq'); // passed
test(testMyArray(arr1, arr3) == false, 'false if input not eq'); // should say false
```

Any idea how can I modify my `testMyArray` to make a passing statement? What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried tracing your code? It would reveal your mistake quite quickly.

Comment: if (arr1[i] !== arr2[i]) doesnt iterate to all of the elements before returning either true or false.

Comment: You also need to check that `arr1.length === arr2.length`

Comment: what is `array1`?? Did you mean `arr1`?

Comment: Fixed..wrong spelling

Comment: Fixed as in solves your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue 1:

You **always** `return` on the first iteration of the loop

#### Issue 2:

If `arr2` is longer than `arr1`, the extra items aren't considered

#### Fixed code:

```
function testMyArray(arr1, arr2) {
  if (arr1.length !== arr2.length) {
    return false;
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    if (arr1[i] !== arr2[i]) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Passed the two except the last.

Comment: You just need to add the check if the arrays are of equal length, then this will work.

Comment: Your mean like this? array1[i] !== array2[i] && array1[i] !== array2[i]

Comment: @JamesHedegon You mean `testMyArray(arr1, arr4)` returns true but should return false?

Comment: array1[i].length !== array2[i].lengt

Comment: @JamesHedegon Alright, I've updated the answer to account for that. If the two arrays have different lengths, they're definitely not equal, so the function returns `false` immediately and skips the loop altogether

Answer (score 0):

Your variable name is wrong in testMyArray(). Plus others mentioned other issues.

```
function test(expected, testName) {
  if (!expected) {
    console.log(testName);
  } else {
    console.log('test passed');
  }
}

function testMyArray(arr1, arr2) {
// fix
  for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    if (arr1[i] !== arr2[i]) {
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }
}


var arr1 = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10];
var arr2 = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10];
var arr3 = [2, 10, 6, 8, 12];
var arr4 = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12];

test(testMyArray(arr1, arr4) === false, 'false if input not eq') // should say false
test(testMyArray(arr1, arr2) === true, 'true if input eq'); // passed
test(testMyArray(arr1, arr3) == false, 'false if input not eq'); // should say false
```

Comment: Wheres the fix?

Comment: You edited. instead of arr1.length you had array1.length

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
function test(expected, testName) {
  if (!expected) {
    console.log(testName);
  } else {
    console.log('test passed');
  }
  }

function testMyArray(arr1, arr2) {
 var count = 0;
   // check the equality of the two array length
   if(arr1.length!==arr2.length){
        return false;
    }
  /*
  // this would return true as soon as checking the first
  // element of the two arrays since they are equal
      for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
         if (arr1[i] !== arr2[i]) {
          return false;
         } else {
          return true;
        }
     }
  */ 

 
  // this would make a count if any of the elements are unequal
  for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    if (arr1[i] !== arr2[i]) {
      count++;
    } 
  }

  // if inequality has been recorded then this return false.
  // otherwise, it returns true
  if(count !==0){
     return false;
  } else {
     return true;
  }
}


var arr1 = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10];
var arr2 = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10];
var arr3 = [2, 10, 6, 8, 12];
var arr4 = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12];

test(testMyArray(arr1, arr4) === false, 'false if input not eq') // should say false
test(testMyArray(arr1, arr2) === true, 'true if input eq'); // passed
test(testMyArray(arr1, arr3) == false, 'false if input not eq');
```

Comment: What's not working? Might be helpful to point out what error you're getting, or what unexpected result you're seeing.